# Set difference as subset of a set whose associated probability is $0$. What does that mean?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

Let us start from the event space $\Omega$. Pretend that there exists $\Omega_p$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_p)=1$. I know that

> the events set difference
> $$A\backslash B\tag{1}$$ is a subset of the complement of $\Omega_p$, i.e. a subset of $\Omega_p^C$.

Since we know that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_p)=1$, it follows that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_p^C)=0$, that is $$\text{"almost no point is in } \Omega_p^C\text{"}$$

---

Hence, what does it mean that $$A\backslash B\subset\Omega_p^C\tag{2}$$
?

Comment: It's all about the word "almost", which is relative to the probability measure. If a set has probability $0$, then the probability distribution "thinks" there is nothing there. But this  doesn't mean the set is literally empty. An analogue would be how the rational numbers have Lebesgue measure $0$, and so with respect to measure "almost no real number is rational". So even though there are infinitely many rational numbers, they make up almost nothing in the set of reals (with respect to measure).

Comment: Perfect. So, could I make some conclusion on the set difference $\{A\}\backslash\{B\}$? Does the fact that such a difference is a subset of $\Omega_c^P$ denote that $A=B$ or something like that? @halrankard2

Comment: No, not without more information. It just means that $A\setminus B$ has probability $0$. (Also, $A\setminus B$ is the standard notation. $\{A\}\setminus\{B\}$ is the singleton set containing the element $B$, minus the singleton set containing the element $B$.)

Comment: For example, let $\Omega=[0,1]$ and let $P$ be Lebesgue measure. Let $\Omega_p$ be the irrationals in $[0,1]$, let $B=\emptyset$, and let $A$ be the rationals in $[0,1]$. Then $A\setminus B$ (which is just $A$) is a subset of the complement of $\Omega_p$; but of course $A$ is not equal to $B$ or contained in $B$, etc....

Comment: Great! And if for example we have a stochastic process $X(t,\omega)$ ($\omega\in\Omega$), an interval $I\subset [0,1]$ and a subset $S$ dense in $[0,1]$ such that $$A=(\omega\in\Omega: X(t,\omega)\in\mathbb{R},\forall t\in I\cap S)$$ and $$B=(\omega\in\Omega: X(t,\omega)\in\mathbb{R},\forall t \in I)$$ could we state something on relationship between $A$ and $B$? Or we can just say that $A\backslash B$ has probability $0$? @halrankard2